# Burninate 18.04 and 16.04 tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

These tags [18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/18.04/info) and [16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/16.04/info) have no meaning. I suspect that these are the for the Ubuntu versions 18.04 and 16.04 but still these tags can be misused and may used for different purposes. So I request to burninate these tags.

Comment: There is only one question there.. which seems to be migrated to AskUbuntu... We dont have to do anything. The tag should get cleaned up

Comment: So after the question get migrated the tags get cleaned up automatically?

Comment: If there are no more questions in the tag it gets removed

Comment: So my point is other people might use it for environment specific programming issues.

Comment: Well.. The process seems to be fast-tracked by a Mod.. If it gets recreated..it would need to be blacklisted